# How would I get something like this? How do I get small solder points at the tips?

Tags: microcontroller, pcb, circuit-design, kicad

I want to make a nice visual on a PCB but I am not entirely sure how to get the ends of routes to have little tips like this or how to make the board look like this in all honesty. Does anyone have any tips? Sorry I have never really done this before so I am kind of in deep water currently. I am using KiCad.

[image]

Comment: The ends of the traces are probably test points.

Comment: ConnerWithAnE - Hi, Where did that image come from? If it was copied from somewhere then, to comply with the site rule on [referencing](/help/referencing), please [edit] the question & add the image's source PDF / video / webpage name and its link. TY

Comment: it is unclear what you mean by `solder points`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot really see much detail in your image. So I'm going to asusme some things.

First, you see that the design is golden. This is achieved by two things:

1. You have to expose the copper (exclude it from the soldermask) toi allow it to be plated golden. This is used by applying the F.Mask Layer on the region you want to exclude from the solder mask. See the screenshot. It shows the layout of the front copper plus a rectangle of soldermask exclusion. and the results in the 3D viewer.
2. **You need to instruct your manufacturer to actually gold-plate your PCB**. If it is "only" done in a HASL solder process, the area will not be golden but plated with tin. For most higher end manufacturers, gold is standard. But it might not be for most Chinese prototyping services and requires a small upgrade.
   [image: Front Solder Mask Removed]

I don't see if there are solder dots on the end of the lines. I don't think this is what you meant. If not, ignore the following. If there are some, then the F.Paste Layer has to be placed there. See the screenshot.
[image: Solder Paste Layer]

This layer will make an opening in the paste stencil that is used to apply solder paste and the paste will be placed there before soldering. It will melt and make a solder blob during the reflow soldering.

**Keep in mind, that this only works, if you buy your PCBs with assembly. Otherwise you will only get the bare board and there will be no solderpaste applied obviously. If you don't get assembly, you can most certainly order a stencil to apply the paste yourself. Or place it by hand with some tweezers.**

**Also, keep in mind, that the solder will spread across any exposed (golden) area once it's melted. So your blobs will widen a bit.**

The lines you see can simply be generated with tracks in Kicad.
The round tips can either be placed by adding Round Pads from a foorprint, or by drawing a cricle with the circle tool in the toolbar and editing it to be filled:
You have several options to get something like in your image:

[image: Filled Circle on copper layer.]

1. You draw the image in copper and in the appropriate mask layer twice on top of each other.
2. You use a copper plane and only draw your desing in the Mask layer. That's what I mostly use for my logos.

[image: Soldermask Artwork]

---

You can also use the Image Converter in kicad, see the main window. It can import images and turn them into footprints. Once your artwork becomes to complex to draw in KiCad, you can draw it in any tool. (It has to be black/white with sharp color edges) and import it to a specific layer. in your case, the F.Mask Layer.

Use the 3D viewer to check your results!
Good luck.

---

As the other answer suggests, it is also possible to get this by routing a foorprint and placing testpoints at the end.
There are circular testpoints in the kicad library. But for anything smaller you would have to make your own footprint using a round pad.
(You can disable the white silkscreen of the footrpint to get the desired result).

[image: Testpoint]

However, if the thing you want to do is not electrically relevant and an "artwork" I would import it as an image. If it is something electrically relevant, I would do it in Kicad with testpoints, footprints, etc...

Comment: Most retail board makers have ENIG (this gold) avaialble at little cost.  by retail I mean those who sell their service on-line and are willing to make small quantities.

Answer (score 2):

That looks like the footprint for a surface-mount IC with a ground/heatsink pad on the underside of the part.

The copper dots are probably through-hole pads (I haven't used a footprint like that myself),

The wider parts at the ends of the tracks will also be part of the footprint - they are the pads that you solder the component pins to.